# Given a list of elements, how can I set an active class on the clicked element? How can I ensure exactly 1 element is always active at a time?

Tags: javascript, css

I have a set of buttons and want to be able to toggle an active class when a button is clicked.

I’d also like for only one button, and exactly one button, to be active at a time.

```
<section id="color-palette">
        <button class="color selected">Black</button>
        <button class="color">Generate</button>
        <button class="color">Generate</button>
        <button class="color">Generate</button>
    </section>

function selectedColor(){ buttonOne.classList.toggle('selected');
}    

buttonOne.addEventListener('click', selectedColor);
```

Comment: sorry i formated it wrong, hope everyone can understand it

Comment: Hopefully the answer below addresses your question.

Comment: Your aswer was perfect i just need a way to toggle off the selected from the other elements, thanks.

Comment: Sure thing, happy it helped. Feel free to upvote the answer as useful if it helped solve the problem.

Comment: can you give me some light to how let just one have the selected color at a time ?

Comment: See my updated answer along with solution to your second question.

Comment: yeah it works mate, but i cant let any button be without the selected class. in this case if a click button one every class disapear with the class. i dont want you to do the code but can you give me some ideias?

Comment: See updated answer. Please take away from this that you need to provide much more detail in your original question and think through exactly what want to ask next time. This saves a lot of time for both poster and those contributing to answers, but more importantly it makes your question clear so that it's more useful to others who might have the same issue. Your current question has no explanation, just a title without much context. I highly encourage you to update the question to describe your problem so it's clear to others what you're asking :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Question 1

If you simply want to toggle each button:

```
const buttons = Object.values(document.getElementsByClassName("color"));

function selectedColor(e) {
  e.target.classList.toggle("selected");
  console.log(e.target.classList)
}

buttons.forEach(function(button) {
  button.addEventListener("click", selectedColor);
});
```

### Question 2

For your second question, if you want to ensure that *exactly* one button is always assigned the active class at any give time:

```
const buttons = Object.values(document.getElementsByClassName("color"));

function selectedColor(e) {
  buttons.forEach(function (button) {
    if (button === e.target) {
      if (!button.classList.contains("selected")) {
        // only add active class if the current button does not have it
        button.classList.add("selected");
      }
    } else {
      button.classList.remove("selected");
    }
  });
  console.log(buttons);
}

buttons.forEach(function (button) {
  button.addEventListener("click", selectedColor);
});
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/toggle-button-class-one-selected-always-1bhw87

### Explanation

Getting the button elements from the DOM returns an `HTMLCollection`. `Object.values()` is a quick way to get an array of the resulting HTML elements so we can loop over and target each one.

First, we loop over each element and add our event listener.

```
buttons.forEach(function(button) {
  button.addEventListener("click", selectedColor);
});
```

For question 1, in the event handler, we simply toggle the class.

For question 2, in the event handler, we need to once again target all the buttons to get an account of the current classes for each button. So, we loop over the button elements.

Within our loop, when dealing with the current button, we first add a condition to handle the clicked button differently than the rest.

```
if (button === e.target) {
```

If the event target (element we clicked) is the current button, we want to ensure the button has the active class. We can do this by checking if the active class is already added. *If not*, then we add it.

```
if (button === e.target) {
  if (!button.classList.contains("selected")) {
    // only add active class if the current button does not have it
    button.classList.add("selected");
  }
```

Finally, if the current button isn't the clicked button, we need to ensure the active class is removed.

```
if (button === e.target) {
  if (!button.classList.contains("selected")) {
    // only add active class if the current button does not have it
    button.classList.add("selected");
  }
} else {
  button.classList.remove("selected");
}
```

This ensures only one button has the active class at a time.

Comment: Mate i hope i can think fast like that one day, thanks for the help!